# Class not found in Java Servlet using Maven

Tags: java, maven, gson

I tried to import the Gson library from Google using Maven but when I run my web application, I receive error that the Gson class isn't found. I tried to put provided for the scope of the Gson library but it didn't do anything.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>Skeleton</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**TestServlet.java**

```
package servlets;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Philippe on 2016-05-10.
 */
@WebServlet(name = "/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() ;
        list.add("item1");
        list.add("item2");
        Gson gson = new Gson() ;
        String json = gson.toJson(list) ;
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
    }
}
```

**log**

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
>     at servlets.TestServlet.doGet(TestServlet.java:34)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

Is there anything I'm missing ?

Comment: have you tried to do a "mvn clean install"?

Comment: Note: "provided" means "target runtime already provides it". https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope Your target runtime is Tomcat. It doesn't provide Gson out the box, so you have to provide it via the webapp yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's more clear to me now why provided didn't do anything. That might be a stupid question but isn't Maven supposed to provide Gson if I put it in my dependencies ? What should I do to fix my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Just try by removing `<scope>compile</scope>` as documented in the [site](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2).

```
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```